# Connecting GPS device

Tags: android, gps

I appreciate any help , am stuck actually. So, I am Asking how to connect a GPS device (external GPS) to a cell phone (containing the application) , in order to send informations about its location **without** using USB cable or bluetooth.

Comment: what else is there? wifi?

Comment: did not get the device yet, but the purpose is connecting it from large distance to cell phone or computer

Comment: that's not what I asked. What's wrong with wifi?

Comment: not sure about the coverage

Comment: it sounds like you don't even know what you want to do, maybe figure that out before you start asking specific questions

Comment: well , I have the idea. but if I knew how to implement it I wouldn't be asking you :/ .I thought my question was clear .. you asked about wifi let's suppose that the gps device is 10km far from your cell-phone , how is it possible to send nmea woof from that distance !

Comment: if those are the distances then the only way is to use a client/server over the internet

Comment: exactly , and the gps device is my client , but I am wondering how my serveur(pc-or cellphone)  will detect gps device from that distance  ?  (for example if the gps is near the serveur will detect it through bluetooth, but what if it's far )

Comment: the gps device is the server, so it being "near the server" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I get what you mean, the server should always be waiting for connections . so how my client will connect to this gps !(for example if am using a bluetooth gps , my client will search for all devices in its bluetooth coverage zoon and then the client choose the device ) , which is not in my case ! , so how the client will connect to the server !?

Comment: if the only i/o for your gps is bluetooth and it isn't in range of anything to transmit, what you want is impossible.

Comment: of course it's possible ,soon as I get the model of the gps device , will send it to you . Still don't know the problem ! if you had a car with a gps tracker and you're home and you want to know where is it !